# Office Web Apps Server 2013 without SharePoint

Tags: ms-office

I've noticed Microsoft has released a new version of Office Web Apps Server 2013, which is a standalone product now.

I'm looking for an engine that I can convert Word/Excel and PowerPoint documents into web-friendly versions (HTML5) for an application I've built that uploads these documents to S3 and I thought Office Web Apps Server 2013 standalone would work.

I don't want to use Google Docs, but rather use a solution that I'm hosting myself.

Reading the Office Web Apps Server documentation, it doesn't specify whether or not I need to have a SharePoint server license. I've tried deploying Office Web Apps Server on a Windows 2012 server on Microsoft Azure, and while the software installs, it is unable to render any documents that I'm pointing to it from an external URL (a publicly accessible S3 bucket).

Does anyone know the particular requirements of Office Web Apps Server 2013 to work properly? The website does state that it can be used to view documents from an external URL which is how I'm trying to use it. But since its a new product, there isn't that much information I was able to find on it other than Microsoft's deployment instructions.

Comment: looking to find out the same

Comment: you guys get any answer on this?

Comment: I am trying the same thing (deploying Office Web Apps Server on a Windows 2012 server) following the below link which gives a detailed step by step instructions to Deploy the WAC server. I am stuck in a step where they are executing a command (New-OfficeWebAppsFarm -InternalURL "http://wittyparrot.com" -AllowHttp -EditingEnabled) on powershell. I don't know what should be the server name. FYI I have custom WOPI Host application running on my machine (Windows 10 Local Machine)and am trying to interact it with WAC (trying to deploy on Windows 2012 RC) as WOPI client.what will be the server name?